# How to override "active configuration" when the theme is installing?

Tags: installation, configuration

I have a theme that imports configuration when is installed. The problem is when the configuration is already there and is active.

> Unable to install MYTHEME, field.field.user.user.user_picture,
>   field.storage.node.body, field.storage.node.field_image,
>   field.storage.user.user_picture, node.type.article,
>   views.view.frontpage already exist in active configuration.

I know these errors are because the configuration is already on the site.

How can I override the configuration with a new configuration that is carried from my theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You can provide only configuration for your module or create new configuration entities. You can "override" the default configuration only by profile, not module or theme.

But you can use hook_install to programmatically override whatever you want.

When it comes to themes, the only configuration that you should provide is block instances and your theme's settings. Of course if you have some advanced blocks you can also provide block types and field storage and instances for them.

Comment: its possible to override all my configuration files ? If so how ? hook_install example that I have seen are very specify to a value but I have not seen an example that it overrides the entire file.

Comment: To override existing configuration use \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($name) instead of \Drupal:config($name) since the latter is read-only.

Comment: $name = to the name of file ?

Comment: I have run to so many issues try to "overwrite" configuration. Its better to avoid doing that..