# How attach a Custom Field do it by code to a Custom Type Page

Tags: 8, entities

I create by YAML files a Field Custom, using the next documentation:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/programming-custom-fields-into-your-content-type

In this tutorial attach the field to Custom Type "car_brand" created by code, in my case I need attach the custom field to the Custom Type "page", he come default in drupal.

How I can attach the field to "page" content type?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create or change the file attaching the field to instead be attached to the page content type:

First we'll have to rename it: `field.field.node.page.field_brand_information.yml`

Secondly, we should be fine just changing all the references from car_brand to the page bundle instead:

```
# field.field.node.page.field_brand_information.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_brand_information
    - node.type.page
  module:
    - text
id: node.page.field_brand_information
field_name: field_brand_information
entity_type: node
bundle: page
label: 'Brand Information'
description: 'More specific information about the car brand'
required: false
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  display_summary: false
field_type: text_with_summary
```

Generally this approach is quite tedious and I agree as also pointed out in the article that you rather do it through the UI and then export the files appropriately.

Comment: In the tutorial they create two files core.entity_form_display.node.page.default, core.entity_view_display.node.page.default. When I install the module show me both files "already exist in active configuration".

Comment: Yes. The content type Page already exists and therefor its display configuration for the form display and entity_view does so as well. It looks like Drupal does not handle these overrides for you. Here are some relevant links: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186421/how-to-override-active-configuration-when-the-theme-is-installing
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187476/how-to-override-configuration-from-a-file?rq=1